# Angular 2 and ag-grid error TS2322 defining a constructor

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm following this guide I found online [Tutorial: Angular 2 Datatable with Sorting, Filtering and Resizable Columns](http://4dev.tech/2016/02/tutorial-angular-2-datatable-with-sorting-filtering-and-resizable-columns/) - it seems like the simplest tutorial I could find that would ease me into the ag-grid library before I can dig deeper into it's documentation. I've copy pasted their code onto my project, the only difference is that I have a bunch other components and services for other things I've been experimenting but this shouldn't be a conflict.

The error I'm getting says

```
error TS2322: Type '{ [x: number]: undefined; rowData: { "name": string; "country": string; "city": string; "email": ...' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: undefined; rowData: { "name": string; "country": string; "city": string; "email": ...'.
```

I'm not sure what to make of it, here is the constructor.
    constructor(private _tableDataService: TableData, private _httpService:

```
HTTPTestService){
        this.gridOptions = {
            rowData: this.myRowData,
            columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFilter: true
        }
    }
```

I'll share the full component on my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Thaenor/f1d3bf6073573a016b60)
Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try this because of the error message "... is not assignable to type 'any[]' ...":

```
gridOptions: any = {}; // <------

constructor(private _tableDataService: TableData,
            private _httpService: HTTPTestService) {
    this.gridOptions = {
        rowData: this.myRowData,
        columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true
    }
}
```

You initialize the `gridOptions` as an array and then you set it as an object...